# @Client doesn't receive body from /measure endpoint

Tags: micronaut

I try to retrieve measures using @Client interface. When I use my own loosely types classes:

```
data class Tags(
        val tag: String,
        val values: List<String>
)

data class Metrics(
        val names: List<String>?,
        val name: String?,
        val measurements: List<Map<String, Any>>?,
        val availableTags: List<Tags>?
)
```

and interface:

```
@Client("/metrics")
interface MetricsClient {

    @Get("{/name}")
    fun metrics(name: String? = null): Metrics
}
```

I got data I expected, but it I try to use classes defined in the endpoint to have code in-sync with server Client reports "empty body" response.

Code with doesn't work:

```
@Client("/metrics")
interface MetricsClient {

    @Get("/")
    fun metricsList(): MetricsEndpoint.MetricNames

    @Get("/{name}")
    fun metricsDetails(name: String): MetricsEndpoint.MetricDetails
}
```

The first call to `client.metricsList()` throws exception saying that the body is empty.

What's wrong with this code? Why it doesn't work?

EDIT:
I enabled DEBUG for everything and this is what I got by reloading the page which using these URLs:

```
23:22:27.683 [pool-1-thread-7] DEBUG i.m.context.DefaultBeanContext - Resolved existing bean [io.micronaut.health.HeartbeatTask@55d58825] for type [class io.micronaut.health.HeartbeatTask] and qualifier [null]
23:22:27.683 [pool-1-thread-7] DEBUG i.m.c.e.ApplicationEventPublisher - Publishing event: io.micronaut.health.HeartbeatEvent[source=io.micronaut.http.server.netty.NettyEmbeddedServerInstance@2d64160c]
23:22:27.683 [pool-1-thread-7] DEBUG i.m.context.DefaultBeanContext - Resolving beans for type: <HeartbeatEvent> io.micronaut.context.event.ApplicationEventListener 
23:22:29.469 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-14] DEBUG i.m.h.server.netty.NettyHttpServer - Server localhost:8080 Received Request: GET /khal
23:22:29.469 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-14] DEBUG i.m.h.s.netty.RoutingInBoundHandler - Matching route GET - /khal
23:22:29.469 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-14] DEBUG i.m.h.s.netty.RoutingInBoundHandler - Matched route GET - /khal to controller class com.helpchoice.kotlin.mn.management.$EndpointsControllerDefinition$Intercepted
23:22:29.473 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-16] DEBUG i.m.http.client.DefaultHttpClient - Sending HTTP Request: GET /metrics
23:22:29.474 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-16] DEBUG i.m.http.client.DefaultHttpClient - Chosen Server: localhost(8080)
23:22:29.476 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-17] DEBUG i.m.h.server.netty.NettyHttpServer - Server localhost:8080 Received Request: GET /metrics
23:22:29.476 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-17] DEBUG i.m.h.s.netty.RoutingInBoundHandler - Matching route GET - /metrics
23:22:29.476 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-17] DEBUG i.m.h.s.netty.RoutingInBoundHandler - Matched route GET - /metrics to controller class io.micronaut.configuration.metrics.management.endpoint.MetricsEndpoint
23:22:29.479 [pool-1-thread-6] DEBUG i.m.h.s.netty.RoutingInBoundHandler - Encoding emitted response object [io.micronaut.configuration.metrics.management.endpoint.MetricsEndpoint$MetricNames@719dde52] using codec: io.micronaut.jackson.codec.JsonMediaTypeCodec@6c9320c2
23:22:29.482 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-16] DEBUG i.m.http.client.DefaultHttpClient - Unable to decode response body using codec JsonMediaTypeCodec:Error decoding JSON stream for type [class io.micronaut.configuration.metrics.management.endpoint.MetricsEndpoint$MetricNames]: Cannot construct instance of `io.micronaut.configuration.metrics.management.endpoint.MetricsEndpoint$MetricNames` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
 at [Source: (byte[])"{"names":["executor","executor.active","executor.completed","executor.pool.size","executor.queued","http.client.requests","http.server.requests","jvm.buffer.count","jvm.buffer.memory.used","jvm.buffer.total.capacity","jvm.classes.loaded","jvm.classes.unloaded","jvm.gc.live.data.size","jvm.gc.max.data.size","jvm.gc.memory.allocated","jvm.gc.memory.promoted","jvm.gc.pause","jvm.memory.committed","jvm.memory.max","jvm.memory.used","jvm.threads.daemon","jvm.threads.live","jvm.threads.peak","logback."[truncated 171 bytes]; line: 1, column: 2]
io.micronaut.http.codec.CodecException: Error decoding JSON stream for type [class io.micronaut.configuration.metrics.management.endpoint.MetricsEndpoint$MetricNames]: Cannot construct instance of `io.micronaut.configuration.metrics.management.endpoint.MetricsEndpoint$MetricNames` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
 at [Source: (byte[])"{"names":["executor","executor.active","executor.completed","executor.pool.size","executor.queued","http.client.requests","http.server.requests","jvm.buffer.count","jvm.buffer.memory.used","jvm.buffer.total.capacity","jvm.classes.loaded","jvm.classes.unloaded","jvm.gc.live.data.size","jvm.gc.max.data.size","jvm.gc.memory.allocated","jvm.gc.memory.promoted","jvm.gc.pause","jvm.memory.committed","jvm.memory.max","jvm.memory.used","jvm.threads.daemon","jvm.threads.live","jvm.threads.peak","logback."[truncated 171 bytes]; line: 1, column: 2]
    at io.micronaut.jackson.codec.JsonMediaTypeCodec.decode(JsonMediaTypeCodec.java:139)
    at io.micronaut.http.client.FullNettyClientHttpResponse.convertByteBuf(FullNettyClientHttpResponse.java:239)
    at io.micronaut.http.client.FullNettyClientHttpResponse.lambda$getBody$1(FullNettyClientHttpResponse.java:189)
    at java.util.HashMap.computeIfAbsent(HashMap.java:1126)
    at io.micronaut.http.client.FullNettyClientHttpResponse.getBody(FullNettyClientHttpResponse.java:167)
    at io.micronaut.http.client.FullNettyClientHttpResponse.<init>(FullNettyClientHttpResponse.java:100)
    at io.micronaut.http.client.DefaultHttpClient$10.channelRead0(DefaultHttpClient.java:1743)
    at io.micronaut.http.client.DefaultHttpClient$10.channelRead0(DefaultHttpClient.java:1705)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.micronaut.http.netty.stream.HttpStreamsHandler.channelRead(HttpStreamsHandler.java:186)
    at io.micronaut.http.netty.stream.HttpStreamsClientHandler.channelRead(HttpStreamsClientHandler.java:181)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:438)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:323)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:297)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:253)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:286)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1434)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:965)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:644)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:579)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:496)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:458)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:897)
    at io.micronaut.http.context.ServerRequestContext.with(ServerRequestContext.java:53)
    at io.micronaut.http.context.ServerRequestContext.lambda$instrument$0(ServerRequestContext.java:69)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
23:22:29.483 [pool-1-thread-5] ERROR i.m.r.intercept.RecoveryInterceptor - Type [com.helpchoice.kotlin.mn.management.MetricsClient$Intercepted] executed with error: Empty body
io.micronaut.http.client.exceptions.HttpClientResponseException: Empty body
    at io.micronaut.http.client.BlockingHttpClient.lambda$retrieve$0(BlockingHttpClient.java:141)
    at java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:290)
    at io.micronaut.http.client.BlockingHttpClient.retrieve(BlockingHttpClient.java:141)
    at io.micronaut.http.client.interceptor.HttpClientIntroductionAdvice.intercept(HttpClientIntroductionAdvice.java:501)
    at io.micronaut.aop.MethodInterceptor.intercept(MethodInterceptor.java:41)
    at io.micronaut.aop.chain.InterceptorChain.proceed(InterceptorChain.java:147)
    at io.micronaut.retry.intercept.RecoveryInterceptor.intercept(RecoveryInterceptor.java:74)
    at io.micronaut.aop.MethodInterceptor.intercept(MethodInterceptor.java:41)
    at io.micronaut.aop.chain.InterceptorChain.proceed(InterceptorChain.java:147)
    at com.helpchoice.kotlin.mn.management.MetricsClient$Intercepted.metricsList(Unknown Source)
    at com.helpchoice.kotlin.mn.management.EndpointsController.metrics(EndpointsController.kt:142)
    at com.helpchoice.kotlin.mn.management.$EndpointsControllerDefinition$$exec4.invokeInternal(Unknown Source)
    at io.micronaut.context.AbstractExecutableMethod.invoke(AbstractExecutableMethod.java:145)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext$BeanExecutionHandle.invoke(DefaultBeanContext.java:2447)
    at io.micronaut.web.router.AbstractRouteMatch.execute(AbstractRouteMatch.java:237)
    at io.micronaut.web.router.RouteMatch.execute(RouteMatch.java:123)
    at io.micronaut.http.server.netty.RoutingInBoundHandler.lambda$buildResultEmitter$16(RoutingInBoundHandler.java:1288)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableCreate.subscribeActual(FlowableCreate.java:71)
    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14479)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableMap.subscribeActual(FlowableMap.java:37)
    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14479)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableSwitchIfEmpty.subscribeActual(FlowableSwitchIfEmpty.java:32)
    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14479)
    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14429)
    at io.micronaut.http.context.ServerRequestTracingPublisher.lambda$subscribe$0(ServerRequestTracingPublisher.java:53)
    at io.micronaut.http.context.ServerRequestContext.with(ServerRequestContext.java:53)
    at io.micronaut.http.context.ServerRequestTracingPublisher.subscribe(ServerRequestTracingPublisher.java:53)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFromPublisher.subscribeActual(FlowableFromPublisher.java:29)
    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14479)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableSwitchMap.subscribeActual(FlowableSwitchMap.java:49)
    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14479)
    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14429)
    at io.micronaut.configuration.metrics.binder.web.WebMetricsPublisher.subscribe(WebMetricsPublisher.java:123)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFromPublisher.subscribeActual(FlowableFromPublisher.java:29)
    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14479)
    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14426)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnSubscriber.run(FlowableSubscribeOn.java:82)
    at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ExecutorScheduler$ExecutorWorker$BooleanRunnable.run(ExecutorScheduler.java:260)
    at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ExecutorScheduler$ExecutorWorker.run(ExecutorScheduler.java:225)
    at io.micrometer.core.instrument.composite.CompositeTimer.record(CompositeTimer.java:79)
    at io.micrometer.core.instrument.Timer.lambda$wrap$0(Timer.java:126)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
23:22:29.484 [pool-1-thread-5] ERROR i.m.h.s.netty.RoutingInBoundHandler - Unexpected error occurred: Empty body
io.micronaut.http.client.exceptions.HttpClientResponseException: Empty body
    at io.micronaut.http.client.BlockingHttpClient.lambda$retrieve$0(BlockingHttpClient.java:141)
    at java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:290)
    at io.micronaut.http.client.BlockingHttpClient.retrieve(BlockingHttpClient.java:141)
    at io.micronaut.http.client.interceptor.HttpClientIntroductionAdvice.intercept(HttpClientIntroductionAdvice.java:501)
    at io.micronaut.aop.MethodInterceptor.intercept(MethodInterceptor.java:41)
    at io.micronaut.aop.chain.InterceptorChain.proceed(InterceptorChain.java:147)
    at io.micronaut.retry.intercept.RecoveryInterceptor.intercept(RecoveryInterceptor.java:74)
    at io.micronaut.aop.MethodInterceptor.intercept(MethodInterceptor.java:41)
    at io.micronaut.aop.chain.InterceptorChain.proceed(InterceptorChain.java:147)
    at com.helpchoice.kotlin.mn.management.MetricsClient$Intercepted.metricsList(Unknown Source)
    at com.helpchoice.kotlin.mn.management.EndpointsController.metrics(EndpointsController.kt:142)
    at com.helpchoice.kotlin.mn.management.$EndpointsControllerDefinition$$exec4.invokeInternal(Unknown Source)
    at io.micronaut.context.AbstractExecutableMethod.invoke(AbstractExecutableMethod.java:145)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext$BeanExecutionHandle.invoke(DefaultBeanContext.java:2447)
    at io.micronaut.web.router.AbstractRouteMatch.execute(AbstractRouteMatch.java:237)
    at io.micronaut.web.router.RouteMatch.execute(RouteMatch.java:123)
    at io.micronaut.http.server.netty.RoutingInBoundHandler.lambda$buildResultEmitter$16(RoutingInBoundHandler.java:1288)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableCreate.subscribeActual(FlowableCreate.java:71)
    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14479)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableMap.subscribeActual(FlowableMap.java:37)
    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14479)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableSwitchIfEmpty.subscribeActual(FlowableSwitchIfEmpty.java:32)
    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14479)
    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14429)
    at io.micronaut.http.context.ServerRequestTracingPublisher.lambda$subscribe$0(ServerRequestTracingPublisher.java:53)
    at io.micronaut.http.context.ServerRequestContext.with(ServerRequestContext.java:53)
    at io.micronaut.http.context.ServerRequestTracingPublisher.subscribe(ServerRequestTracingPublisher.java:53)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFromPublisher.subscribeActual(FlowableFromPublisher.java:29)
    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14479)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableSwitchMap.subscribeActual(FlowableSwitchMap.java:49)
    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14479)
    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14429)
    at io.micronaut.configuration.metrics.binder.web.WebMetricsPublisher.subscribe(WebMetricsPublisher.java:123)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFromPublisher.subscribeActual(FlowableFromPublisher.java:29)
    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14479)
    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14426)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnSubscriber.run(FlowableSubscribeOn.java:82)
    at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ExecutorScheduler$ExecutorWorker$BooleanRunnable.run(ExecutorScheduler.java:260)
    at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ExecutorScheduler$ExecutorWorker.run(ExecutorScheduler.java:225)
    at io.micrometer.core.instrument.composite.CompositeTimer.record(CompositeTimer.java:79)
    at io.micrometer.core.instrument.Timer.lambda$wrap$0(Timer.java:126)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
23:22:29.484 [pool-1-thread-5] DEBUG i.m.h.s.netty.RoutingInBoundHandler - Encoding emitted response object [Internal Server Error: Empty body] using codec: io.micronaut.jackson.codec.JsonMediaTypeCodec@6c9320c2
```

Comment: Need more information. Try enabling trace logging for the package `io.micronaut.http.client`

Comment: @Graeme, I added the logback.

Comment: Error decoding JSON stream for type [class io.micronaut.configuration.metrics.management.endpoint.MetricsEndpoint$MetricNames]: Cannot construct instance of `io.micronaut.configuration.metrics.management.endpoint.MetricsEndpoint$MetricNames` (no Creators, like default construct, exist)

Can you identify why is above error coming in your case, It may be due to serialization of class, how about implementing you class with Serializable interface.

Comment: This is my point: this is not my class, but one provided by Micronaut.

Answer (score 0):

The way I fixed this is by explicitly stating the type as an `Argument`

```
client.toBlocking()
            .exchange(request, Argument.of(Payload::class.java, DataDto::class.java))
```

where the return type of my endpoint is `Payload<DataDto>`

When doing:

```
client.toBlocking()
            .exchange<RequestDto, Payload<DataDto>>(request)
```

The body type seems to get lost somewhere deep in the `exchange` method.